# Why does the WebBrowser overlaps other controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm currently working on a project using WPF and C# and XAML, and I came up with this issue:

I have created a new column (previously there were only 2), and added a TabControl, TabItem and a Stack Panel, to make it similar to the other column. But, when I resize it, it overlaps the other column, even though the min width is set to 0 (or 1).

```
   <TabControl Name="tabSideBarHelp" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="8,4,4,4" Padding="4" MinWidth="100">
            <TabItem Header="Help">
                <StackPanel>
                    <WebBrowser Grid.Row="3" Height="93" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
```

[image: This is the WebBrowser overlapping]

Comment: Needz moar [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/102937).  Is that white box part of the problem, or did you put that there to redact some private information?

Comment: It is the WebBrowser overlapping... Part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with how the `WebBrowser` works, and it affects `WindowsFormsHost` controls as well. Basically, the `WebBrowser` doesn't participate in WPF's usual rendering flow, so it doesn't get composited into a WPF window in the way that WPF controls are. Instead, it gets drawn after everything else in whatever region it occupies, thus overlapping any WPF controls which should be appearing on top of the `WebBrowser` control.

Unfortunately this means you have to be really careful not to let anything overlap a `WebBrowser` control, because you'll get this kind of rendering problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm going to try another approach.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, setting the min-width won't prevent your ui element to resize *above* the specified min-width. Maybe you wanted to set the max-width.

Second of all, the web-browser is a IE frame, not a wpf native control so do expect weirder behaviors from it

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to be more careful!